# pass starting variables to php

Tags: jquery

i am trying to have it so that when a page opens, it shows the current month and year in a div named display. there are 3 links, previous...reset...next. One click I want to reload the content in the display div with the appropriate data...being next month...last month..etc.

I have the reset link working but I cannot figure out how to pass the month and year variables so the script knows where to go next. I also need it so that you can continually press the next or previous links to continue counting down or up. I know i need to add logic for months 1 and 12 to affect the years...but i need to figure out this part first as the year changes would be easy enough for me.
heres a link to the code on a page
http://www.intarsiaplans.com/thepage.php

Comment: why do you need php for that? All the logic can be on the client side

Comment: because php is what i am comfortable with..very new to all this js stuff. the php page it submits to has been very simplified just so i can figure out how to change the month. the submit php page is going to be running all my queries and building a calendar to be displayed in the original page

Answer (score 0):

All you now need to do is:

1. Pass the current month and year as a part of the AJAX request, along with the type of request (next/previous)
2. Grab that data in the backend and compute the response according to the parameters received. For example, if month=6, year=2011 and request_type="next", generate the calendar markup for 7/2011 and send it back to the browser.
3. Replace the old calendar (that's what I assume you're trying to display) with the new one and also replace the values of the month and year on the page with the new ones.

Comment: yes thats what im trying to do, i just simplified the code to figure out how to do it. I can't figure out how to actually pass the $month and $year with the ajax request.

Comment: <div id="month">6</div>

var ajax_url = "/get_calendar?month=" + $("#month").text();

$.ajax({
    url: ajax_url,
    success: function(data) {...}
});

Comment: hmm thats over my head. nevermind, i cheated and just used sessions to hold the month and year...seems to work fine